# How to delegate scope in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, scope, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I have a method `onBind()` that I want to use with a scope of `binding`, is there a way to achieve this?

Currently, I have a variable (“binding: T”) and an abstract function `onBind()` in `BaseBindableFragment`, and in my implementation I use `with(binding){}` to scope `onBind()`. I want to avoid using `with(binding)` and make it so that in implementation I get `onBind() { this: T -> }`

**My abstract class**

```
abstract class BaseBindableFragment<T : ViewDataBinding> : Fragment() {
    protected lateinit var binding: T
        private set

    protected abstract val layout: Int
        @LayoutRes get

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layout, container, false)
        // Wrap with(binding){onBind()} in a way that `onBind` executes with `binding` as `this`
        onBind()
        return binding.root
    }

    protected abstract fun onBind()
}
```

**And then in my implementation**

```
override fun onBind() = with(binding) {  // <- I want to avoid this "= with(binding)" line
    lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    viewModel = myViewModel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected abstract fun T.onBind()
```

and

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layout, container, false)
binding.onBind()
return binding.root
```

The implementation becomes

```
override protected fun T.onBind() {
    lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    viewModel = myViewModel
}
```

(or e.g. `MyBinding.onBind()` if your class extends `BaseBindableFragment<MyBinding>`)